# VBA code to open many word forms and import data to Excel

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I'm trying to write VBA in Excel to loop through many Word documents (up to 1,500 or more) and extract the form field data for each document into a separate line in the same spreadsheet.  Unfortunately, the time frame is tight and my VBA knowledge is seriously lacking.

I've created the Frankenstein-esque module below after gleaning what I could from other people who've tried to do similar things.  I'm not sure how to resolve the error I'm getting now and not even positive I'm going about it the right way.  When I execute the code below, I get "Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)".  It appears to be choking on For Each loop.  I assume there's a variable definition or assignment that's incorrect.

I wanted to write this as Excel VBA to ensure that the Word form can be distributed to my users in the near future while I get this VBA module working properly.  Those forms need to be sent out this week and they'll start coming back to me immediately.  In past years, the staff in this department has done mass data entry to port the form data to Excel--hoping to avoid that this year.

I also considered saving those forms as data only delimited text files, but that would require opening each Word doc, saving as delimited text, concatenating the files together and opening it in Word.  Pretty simple process, but I don't want to open 1,500 Word docs to save them as delimited text.  The rest would be easy.

I believe I also need to beef up the error handling.  When I run another macro which just handles one file, it fails if I have column headings in the spreadsheet and that leaves the Word doc open..  But that's a secondary concern now.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

```
 Sub MultFileLoad()

 'Remember: this code requires a reference to the Word object model

 Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
 Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
 Dim fName As String
 Dim i As Long, Rw As Long, f As Variant
 Dim file
 Dim Path As String

 ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path
 Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

file = Dir("C:\temp\test\*.docx")
Do While file <> ""
wdApp.Documents.Open Filename:=Path & file

 Rw = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 2
 Cells(Rw, 1) = Cells(Rw - 1, 1) + 1
 i = 1
 For Each f In wdDoc.FormFields
 i = i + 1
 On Error Resume Next
 Cells(Rw, i) = f.Result
 Next

wdApp.ActiveDocument.Close

file = Dir()
Loop

wdApp.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
wdApp.Quit
Set wdApp = Nothing

Exits:
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  Still need to do more cleanup and fix other issues, but this code works for my purposes.  Hopefully someone else will find some use for it as well.

```
 Sub MultFileLoad()

 'Remember: this code requires a reference to the Word object model

 Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
 Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
 Dim fName As String
 Dim i As Long, Rw As Long, f As Variant 'Word.FormField
 Dim file
 Dim Path As String

 ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path
 Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

file = Dir("C:\temp\test\*.docx")
Do While file <> ""
wdApp.Documents.Open Filename:=Path & file

 Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Path & file)
 Rw = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 Cells(Rw, 1) = Cells(Rw - 1, 1) + 1
 i = 1
 For Each f In wdDoc.FormFields
 i = i + 1
 On Error Resume Next
 Cells(Rw, i) = f.Result
 Next

wdApp.ActiveDocument.Close

file = Dir()
Loop

wdApp.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
wdApp.Quit
Set wdApp = Nothing

Exits:
wdApp.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
wdApp.Quit
Set wdApp = Nothing

 End Sub
```